# How can I give cloudwatch log permission to invoke a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using this command to stream log to a lambda function.

`aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --filter-name $LAMBDA_NAME --filter-pattern '' --destination-arn $LAMBDA_ARN`

but got this error:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutSubscriptionFilter operation: Could not execute the lambda function. Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to execute your function.`

It seems the log doesn't have permission to invoke my lambda. How can I give the permission? There will be hundreds of log group in my account. I don't want to give permission to each log group one by one. Is there a solution to allow any log to invoke the lambda function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) provide AWS CLI example of how to do it. You would have to adjust the example to your setup:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
    --function-name "helloworld" \
    --statement-id "helloworld" \
    --principal "logs.region.amazonaws.com" \
    --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
    --source-arn "arn:aws:logs:region:123456789123:log-group:TestLambda:*" \
    --source-account "123456789012"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, still getting the message

Answer (score 3):

Cloudformation script

```
LogGroupInvokeLambdaPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt YourLambda.Arn
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: logs.amazonaws.com
    SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
    SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${LambdaThatWritesLogs}:*'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AWS CDK and having this problem, I was able to fix it by adding `"logs:PutLogsEvents"` for the `CloudWatch Logs Group` to the `Lambda Function` `Role Policy`:

```py
logs_processing_lambda = _lambda.Function(...)

cloudwatch_logs = aws_logs.logs.LogGroup(
    scope=self,
    id="logs",
    removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    retention=logs.RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS,
)

lambda_role = iam.PolicyStatement(
    effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions=[
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ],
    resources=[cloudwatch_logs.log_group_arn],
)

logs_processing_lambda.add_to_role_policy(lambda_role)

lambda_dest = aws_logs_destinations.destinations.LambdaDestination(
    fn=logs_processing_lambda, add_permissions=True
)

cloudwatch_logs.add_subscription_filter(
    id="lambdaSubscription",
    destination=lambda_dest,
    filter_pattern=logs.FilterPattern.all_events(),
)
```